# npx pod install fails with empty node_modules

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

**Edit**

I ended up upgrading the iOS version and running iterm2 using rosetta and the pod install finally worked. I was also using `npx pod install` when I should of just used `cd ios/ && pod install`

**Original**

I am setting up a new laptop and finally got around to building my React native app again and am running into an issue with `npx pod install`.

```
npx pod install
Need to install the following packages:
  pod
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.8.0: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /Users/myuser/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/myuser/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2021-11-11T00_43_21_277Z-debug.log
```

When I go looking in these npx directories they never have anything in the node_modules.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't see `pod install` as a command in a quick skim of the pod docs.

Comment: Sorry about that @Trott I trimmed the rest of the logs, from the `npx pod install` command. The rest of the log lines were about deprecated packages.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [`pod` package.json file](https://github.com/yyx990803/pod/blob/97a546c2c632466898947a6ad3480ce6e7e4f99e/package.json), it appears to have a dependency on `pm2` being installed in the module's own `node_modules` directory but that's not how `npx` does things. So that's why you're getting `ENOENT` (which is basically "path not found") for the `pm2` module as your error message.

The easiest solution is probably to not use `npx` with `pod` but to instead do as [the README instructs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pod#installation) and install `pod` as a global package with `npm install -g pod`. Then run `pod install` instead of `npx pod install`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the command wrong so ultimately it was a combo of old iOS versions and me using the wrong command that ran me into this corner. Sorry for wasting your time.